# SQL Server 2005 password changes

Tags: sql-server

I have a mssql 2005 and software (that written by visual basic 6) and the software connects to the mssql.(local)
but the problem is that the "sa" user password changes every day!
And the company that write this software does not give us the password.
And the windows authentication does not work and I think that they delete the windows user too.

I searched on the msdn and ... that i found in the LAN, packets from clients were encrypted in SSL type and sent to the mssql and in a specific packet it includes the username and password of the db, and if that user&pass is same with db user&pass it can be full access to db.

1. I used backtrack & metasploit but it use dictionary for attack but it did not help me .
2. I used wireshark for finding that specific packet , then i think i found it (99% I sure) but that packet has a lot of unclear characters and i could not find those.
3. do you think that if i use SSLSTRIP to make a fake certificate then use it between client and server (as a gateway) can i get that? How?
4. can I use single user mode to add any user to mssql? How?

Answer (score 1):

You are totally approaching this from the wrong angle. You have a software package that goes at extra lengths to prevent access to your data. You problem is the vendor, ditch him. Use a different software, one that has a rational vendor behind it.

Here are the MSDN official, approved, methodology to regain access on a SQL Server that had locked out administrators: [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx)